# PyQt5 + QtOpenGL: QXcbIntegration error

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt

I'm using Debian 8 and python 2.7, anaconda environment.

This is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtOpenGL
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent, flags=QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        self.map = Map(self)


class Map(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Map, self).__init__(parent)
        self.move(11, 148)
        self.setFixedSize(545, 416)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Ui_MainWindow()
form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm getting this error:

```
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is the [./configure](http://pastebin.com/y5sfigF7) from my Qt.

And this is my [glxinfo](http://pastebin.com/tgQVrpFj)

But still not working.

Comment: That code works ok with python3.5+win7+pyqt5.7, problem is on opengl side.... What does glxinfo say?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tgQVrpFj   . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing some libraries. See [this from thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/803737/jetson-tk1/-solved-qt-opengl-eglfs-egl-xcb-x11-wayland-jetson-board-tk1/). If that doesn't work, search for that error message  there are lots of solved questions with)) and many indicate that getting the missing libraries fixed the issue.

Comment: I downloaded all the libraries mentioned in that thread and in other pages. But still doesn't work. Is there a way to know exactly which libraries are missing?